# Error using importdata in Matlab to import .txt files by reading the filenames from a cell

Tags: matlab, file, text

Here is the code (simplified):

```
Dir = dir('C:\Folder\SubFolder_1\Subfolder_2');
allFiles = {Dir(~[Dir.isdir]).name};

for i = 1:length(allFiles);
    data = importdata(allFiles{i});
end
```

The error occurs on the line with the importdata statement:

```
Error using importdata (line 137)
Unable to open file.

Error in Main (line 29)
data = importdata(allFiles{i});
```

Edit 1: From the same directory that I was in in the previous case, when I do,

```
allFiles = {('C:\Folder\SubFolder_1\Subfolder_2\File1.txt'),... 
            ('C:\Folder\SubFolder_1\Subfolder_2\File2.txt')};

for i = 1:length(allFiles);
    data = importdata(allFiles{i});
end
```

I don't get an error and the files read in fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your syntax is okay (atleast it works over here).

Have you checked if your pwd (present workingdirectory) is C:\Folder\SubFolder_1\Subfolder_2 when you run your statement?

If not consider something like concatenating the absolute path:

```
path = 'C:\Folder\SubFolder_1\Subfolder_2\';
Dir = dir(path);
allFiles = {Dir(~[Dir.isdir]).name};

for i = 1:length(allFiles)
    absoluteFileLocation = [path allFiles{i}];
    data = importData(absoluteFileLocation);
end
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I tried concatenating the absolute path as you suggested, but got the same error as before. I then tried just giving it the file names from that same directory to test if it's a directory issue. I got no error when I did it that way. (see Edit 1)

Comment: Oh I see the problem now. When I copy-pasted my actual path name, I forgot to add the '\' after 'Subfolder_2'. I believe it works now, thank you!